# Homebrew install package with a particular version

Tags: imagemagick, homebrew, rmagick

Unfortunately on my MAC I am unable to get the gem "rmagick" to install. I've tried pretty much a all the options.

I had gotten it to install when I used "imagemagick 6.3.9.7".

Therefore, I want to know is there a way to install a particular version of the software using brew ?

Something like

```
brew install imagemagick -v 6.3.9.7
```

Comment: Have a look here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/4158763/2836621

Comment: Ah, nice :) Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Search for available versions with:

```
brew search imagemagick
```

To install a specific version use this forumla: `brew install package@<version>`, in your case it's:

```
brew install imagemagick@6.3.9.7
```

Comment: Thanks! Shall give this a shot.

Comment: I get a "Unknown command: versions". Am I supposed to install a supporting library to brew ?

Comment: Sorry, brew versions <formula> isn't supported anymore, updated the original answer.

Comment: There is now a specific tap for imagemagick versions, perhaps this helps you:

https://github.com/buildtools-version-taps/homebrew-imagemagick-versions-tap

Comment: as of Dec 2017, brew search imagemagick returns - searching taps on github... searching blacklisted, migrated and deleted formulae... - but no results are returned.

Comment: I wandered in upon this question as I was looking for the way myself. Brew maintains *some* older versions *sometimes* for different packages - depending on demand and what they feel like supporting, and this is what is seen with `brew search ___` - but to install a truly outdated package, you need to download the formula locally and install from that.